# stored procedures vs PDO php pl/pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have this query in my PHP class:

```
    $this->query = "SELECT a.x, b.y, c.z FROM aaa a INNER JOIN bbb b ON b.ida = a.ida ";
    $this->query.= "INNER JOIN ccc c ON c.idb = b.idb WHERE a.ida = :ida";
    $this->stmtparam = array(':ida' => $this->ida);
    return parent::fillArray(); // it fills a PDO FETCH_ASSOC array and returns it as JSON
```

suppose that this is a 10 times more complicated query and I have many of this in a company information system;

My question is: **Is it possible to make an stored function in postqresql which do the same and returns a SET of many tables, then fetch the results into an associative array in php?**

Does it worth to do it?

Comment: It depends on what all of this is actually supposed to be doing, but I will say that if this is performing any kind of logic, it is generally advisable to keep this logic out of the data storage layer, and in the application code.

Comment: so, suppose that I want to return the t_employee name, the t_city ID, the t_emp_salary salary, the t_department name, the t_department_manager name WHERE employees worked on 2013-01-01, you would say that this is a "logic" case and it is better to keep it in the application layer?

Comment: @Pudge601 depending on what logic it is it may be best to keep it in the actual query, for example if you are storing binary but wanting to retrieve hex values.

Comment: @GriffLab, true, that's a good example of where you would want to keep that logic in the query; perhaps I should rephrase 'logic' to 'business logic' or 'application logic'

Answer (score 1):

postgresql does not have stored procedures, but you can write a function which is essentially the same thing. I prefer to put complex queries into a function. This way you can make fixes and performance improvements on the database side instead of having to push out new PHP code each time.

Here's a resource that demonstrates how to create a pg function and call it from PHP:
http://pgedit.com/resource/php/pgfuncall

Comment: If it was only for "wrapping" complex queries, I'd prefer a view over a function.

Comment: True, if it's just a query, it can be wrapped into a view for easy access. However, if it has complex data crunching logic where you need to perform loops or calculations or gather things into temp tables, then a function would be preferred.